# There was a service error: 403 in android

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I am making **youtube search video** through my app. For this I have create a project on **google developer console** and provide **credentials** like **package name** and **SHA - 1 certificate** and get `YouTubeApi key` that is use in my project but when i run program it throw `GoogleJsonResponseException exception` with some message. I am not understanding what is that `exception` and how can we resolve it.
below is exception

```
05-07 15:26:23.858 12602-12738/com.dp.videostoreadmin W/System.err: There was a service error: 403 : The Android package name and signing-certificate fingerprint, null and null, do not match the app restrictions configured on your API key. Please use the API Console to update your key restrictions.
```

below is my activity code

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.SearchListResponse;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.SearchResult;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String YOUTUBE_API_KEY = "AIzaSyDielPMOnvIiOh5Rh3MyPRfFTprFmcX0Cw";
    EditText searchText;
    Button submit;
    private static YouTube youtube;
    private static final long NUMBER_OF_VIDEOS_RETURNED = 25;
    String queryKey;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        searchText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        queryKey = searchText.getText().toString();


        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new getSearchResult().execute();
            }
        });
    }



    public class getSearchResult extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {

                youtube = new YouTube.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), new HttpRequestInitializer() {
                    public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
                    }
                }).setApplicationName("VideoStoreAdmin").build();


                YouTube.Search.List search = youtube.search().list("id,snippet");
                search.setKey(YOUTUBE_API_KEY);
                search.setQ(queryKey);
                search.setType("video");
                search.setFields("items(id/kind,id/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/publishedAt,snippet/thumbnails/default/url),nextPageToken");
                search.setMaxResults(NUMBER_OF_VIDEOS_RETURNED);

                // Call the API and print results.
                SearchListResponse searchResponse = search.execute();
                List<SearchResult> searchResultList = searchResponse.getItems();
                if (searchResultList != null) {
                    Log.d("TAG",searchResultList.toString());
                }
            } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
                System.err.println("There was a service error: " + e.getDetails().getCode() + " : "
                        + e.getDetails().getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("There was an IO error: " + e.getCause() + " : " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;


        }
    }



}
```